# Async resolved before than expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I've this function written by myself

```
        async function asyncAreaLoad() {
            console.log( "asyncAreaLoad\t" + config.area + "\t" + room.id );

            let check = await state.PersistanceManager.checkArea( config.area )
            if ( check ) {
                Logger.verbose( `PERSISTANCE:\troom: \t${room.id} EXIST, no Fetch` );
                console.log( "NO FETCH" );
                return;
            }

            const perLoader = state.EntityLoaderRegistry.get( 'persistence' );
            perLoader.setArea( config.area );
            const haveItems = await perLoader.hasData();

            if ( !haveItems ) {
                Logger.verbose( `PERSISTANCE:\t\tArea\t[${config.area}]\t with NO DATA!` );
                console.log( "NO DATA" );
                return;
            }

            let aw = await perLoader.fetchAll();
            console.log( "FETCHED" );

            state.PersistanceManager.addArea( config.area, aw.rooms );
            Logger.verbose( `PERSISTANCE:\t\tArea\t[${config.area}]\t LOADED!` );
            console.log( "Loaded" );
            // state.PersistanceManager.populateArea( config.area );
        }

        await asyncAreaLoad();
```

How you can see by the result the function is fired four times and the name of the area is the same *valinorCastle*.
I was expecting that ***perLoader.fetchAll*** were fired once because the ***addArea*** makes ***checkArea*** to return ***true***.
Instead I got this

**Result:**

```
asyncAreaLoad   valinorCastle   valinorCastleMainRoom
asyncAreaLoad   valinorCastle   valinorCastle2
asyncAreaLoad   valinorCastle   valinorCastle3
asyncAreaLoad   valinorCastle   valinorCastle4
   **FETCHED**
    **AddedArea valinorCastle**
    Loaded
    **FETCHED**
    Loaded
    **FETCHED**
    Loaded
    **FETCHED**
    Loaded
```

Comment: You call `asyncAreaLoad` once ... why is it logged 4 times? Something else is calling `asyncAreaLoad`

Comment: what can call `asyncAreaLoad` can be only that `await` I showed you in all the project. And anyway the callers should be blocked at `checkArea`

Comment: something is calling it multiple times ... the code above is in a function, correct. So how is that function being called

Comment: @JaromandaX that function is insied a function that is an event and is normal that is called each time I've a new room added into an area. But what I was expecting was that `await` blocks the other calls after the first

Comment: no, it won't necessarily block anything since it's called in response to an event - though, it's still not clear how this function in the question is being called

Comment: Can be possible that the `resolved` happening before the end of `asyncAreaLoad` because some function has a Promise that is resolved?

Comment: look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7j3vgLa/) - the button is disabled after two seconds, but the call to disable the button is in an event handler and the disable code is awaited on ... you can see that you can click the button as many times as you like before the first click disables it ... so, async/await is **not** the solution for your paradigm - you'll need to rethink your code

Comment: I thought that async/await works like the lock/unlock in C#. Than the only way is make something in my code that queque the calls and the works those one by one... I do not see any other solution in JS

Comment: No, that's not what async/await does

Comment: Knowing more about the code that calls the (unnamed) function in your question will help in writing an answer. At the moment, if that code exists in entirety inside an event handler, then it's a more complex answer than if the `asyncAreaLoad` function is declared outside the event handler - this is why I've been asking for the code that calls this code for the last 30 minutes

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. The example output does not demonstrate that the returned promise is resolved. It is in fact not resolved, and the outer code is not waiting for it to be.

Comment: @JaromandaX to show you more code it means show you the entire project because there is a Area class that emit an event `roomAdded` when the room is added (of course) and I create a listener that run that bit of code I posted

Comment: right ... anyway, does the answer help?

Comment: I'm going to try your code asap

Comment: @JaromandaX nothing it is still giving the same result

Comment: @JaromandaX https://github.com/RanvierMUD/core/blob/master/src/EventManager.js it is how `emit` works

Comment: well, no idea then - personally I find there is not enough information in the question to give an accurate answer - someone else may come along and help

Comment: what else can help you? you can find the EventManager in that link and here https://github.com/RanvierMUD/core/blob/master/src/Area.js is how `roomAdded` if fired into the `addRoom` function